# generating a random double between 0 and infinity in java

Tags: java, random, nan, infinity

I have this code

and I'm trying to send a random double to the method "fun"

BL is a double equal 1 here

```
   double inf=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
   double rand=inf*R.nextDouble();
   double myrand=fun(rand)*BL;
   mylist.get(i).set_speed(myrand);
```

and here is the "fun" method

```
double fun(double v)
{
   return ((pow(A,K)*exp((-1)*A*v)*pow(v,K-1))/(fact(K-1)));
}
```

But the output of the speed parameter is always NaN

Comment: Infinity is defined in the IEEE 754; however it doesn't mean that it is the value of infinity. See [Wikipedia on IEEE 754 double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Won't multiplying infinity by your randomly generated double always make the value infinity? Doesn't that defeat the random purpose?

Comment: Infinity times a number is always infinity

Comment: Generating a random number between 0 and infinity would take an infinite amount of computing time and infinite storage. I would set my sights a little lower if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line `inf*R.nextDouble();` to `Double.MAX_VALUE * R.nextDouble();` If you also need to get `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` from time to time, then you have to implement an additional if block and randomly return `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` in some of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, infinity isn't reachable by a double. Try this instead

```
double rand = R.nextDouble(Double.MAX_VALUE- 1);
```

That will create a random double between 0 and the maximum value for a double

Comment: nextDouble();
take no parameters

Answer (score 2):

To get a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than Double.MAX_VALUE:

```
double r = Math.random()*Double.MAX_VALUE
```

Then simply pass the result to your function.

Comment: Won't this generate a random double and then multiply it by the max value, causing it to exceed the max value?

Comment: No, because `Math.random()` always returns a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Well, @Leet-Falcon, I can't remove my downvote unless you edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a number between 0 and infinity.

Because if you could you would get a number with infinity numbers.

1.But you can get a random number with a max value like:

```
int random(int max)
{
    return (int) (Math.random() * max);
}
```

2.With a minimal number:

```
int random(int min, int max)
{
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

3.Type this if you don't want any decimals:

```
int random(int min, int max)
{
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * range) + min);
}
```

Otherwise if you want to round it down or up:

```
//round down
(int) Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + min);

//round up
(int) Math.ceil((Math.random() * range) + min);
```

Message a number:

```
//between 500 1000 (function 2 or 3)
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, random(500, 1000));

//or just maximal: 1000 (function 1)
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, random(1000));
```

Hope it helps :)